# how to configured shell_api parameter in carrierwave with mini magic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave, minimagick

My project use the carrierwave 0.9.0 with mini_magick 4.2.10 so I want to know how to configured the shell_api parameter in mini_magick using carrierwave.

```
MiniMagick.configure do |config|
  config.shell_api = "posix-spawn"
end
```

Where should I write this configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Using Carrierwave its generate image_uploader.rb file in Uploader folder and its

```
include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
```

So configure the shell_api parameter like that

```
MiniMagick.shell_api = "posix-spawn"
```

And its work fine.

Answer (score 0):

add it to an initializer, like for example `config/initializers/minimagick.rb`:

```
MiniMagick.configure do |config|
  config.shell_api = "posix-spawn"
end
```

if you get an error `cannot load such file -- minimagick (LoadError)` launching the app, you'll need to include the gem in your Gemfile:

```
gem "mini_magick"
```